# How does Google know my work pc's search history?

Tags: google-search

Whenever I've searched for something on my work pc, it'll turn up on my android phone afterwards. (I'm not signed in with my private google account on my work pc). Can google see that my phone is next to the pc, and therefore presume it is my pc as well?

Comment: Google links accounts. If you ever signed into e.g. Google Play on the desktop, then they'll associate your desktop to your Android, at least via Cookies. But the link could be more indirect as well, e.g. if you use Google mail on your desktop, YouTube, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Google has no way to "See" that the phone and computer are near each other. Sure they could use GPS on your phone, but it can't do that for your PC. And due to the many other computers, it can't assume what phone is linked to what user on which computer.

What has probably happened, is that your phone is linked to your work Google account. Possibly to access Gmail. If this is the case, then that is what is causing the link.

Another thing to point out, Google like to bind some searches to IPs. (If you don't believe me, go to YouTube at your house, then at an Internet Café. The recommended videos change drasticly.)

Comment: As i said, I'm not connected with my google account on the pc. The only way these two have been connected ever, is through a mail i sent.

Comment: Also, i'm not using the wifi at my job, for my phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google cannot presume which pc you're using by your phone position. Are you really sure you never logged into your Google account from work? Neither in Google page nor in Chrome application?

If you want to be sure, check your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard) page and see your Search History and from which devices you connected.

I also suggest to set up 2-step verification, to be sure no one will use your account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome, then that might jut be the issue. If you signed in from your work PC in your google acoount using chrome (or any chromium-based browser, like citrio) then it will automatically connect to your browser. To fix this, you can just enable guest browsing and use chrome in incognito mode. And that's it. Your browsing history will not turn up on your droid.

Answer (score 0):

> Can google see that my phone is next to the pc, and therefore presume it is my pc as well?

No. Obviously I can use my phone alongside someone else' PC. If it works this way that would be huge problem.

If you are sure you never logged in to your private Google account on your work PC, can you also check if you have ever logged into ANY OTHER website, that you also log in to on your phone? There is third-party cookie and many websites incl. Google use that to collate user data together (a.k.a. to track users, mostly for ad purpose), so they know that is the same user on different websites..

Answer (score -1):

If you're signed into Google, the history for your Google ID is used.  Otherwise, most likely they're using IP address, which for many office networks is static.

Comment: I never saw my search terms pop up on a colleague's screen.

Comment: Each machine behind the network router still has a unique address -- that's what keeps your requested web page from going to a buddy's browser, your email from opening in your buddy's Outlook, etc.  However, unlike most home internet service, those addresses don't change (my home router can change address every 24 hours or every time it restarts, though it doesn't always do so).

Comment: Additionally, your phone shows in the same subnet if you're connected to the office wifi (even the guest wifi), so even if both aren't signed into Google, it may see the two devices/browsers as being related.  Most likely, though, your phone is signed into Google, and so is your office machine's browser (that's cookie-related, so a cookie clear will disconnect until you log in again).